# Uploading Images to S3 for larger files

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I had been trying to upload images to `s3` using the following code

```
function(base64Image){
let imageBuffer = new Buffer(base64Image.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, ""), 'base64');
    return S3.putObject({
      Bucket: `my-bucket`,
      Key: `my-key`,
      Body: imageBuffer,
      ACL: 'public-read',
      ContentType: "image/jpeg",
      ContentEncoding: "base64"
    }).promise()
      .then((response) => {
          })
          .catch((error) => {

          })
      })
}
```

It works perfectly but not for larger files, so starting `2.0 MB` it starts to occasionally work.

How do you solve this?

Cheers

Comment: Try to use multer with s3 https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer-s3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the module *superagent* (https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent) that supports file uploading with formData. Then, in the backend, you need to use *multer* (https://github.com/expressjs/multer), to get the file.

In the frontend file

```
//Method to do the request
superagent
.post(/register")
.attach("avatar", uploadedImage)
```

uploadedImage has the image content

In the backend file

```
var multer = require('multer')
var upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' })
import fs from 'fs-extra'

exports.uploadImage = ((name, image) => {
    AWS.config.update({ 'region': process.env.GROUP_REGION, 'accessKeyId': process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, 'secretAccessKey': process.env.AWS_SECRET_KEY })
    var s3Bucket = new AWS.S3({ params: { Bucket: process.env.S3_BUCKET_NAME } })
    var data = { Key: name, Body: image }
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        s3Bucket.putObject(data, function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('Error uploading data: ', data)
                reject(err)
            } else {
                console.log('succesfully uploaded the image!')
                resolve(data)
            }
        })
    })
})

router.post('/register', upload.single('avatar'), (req, res, next) => {
        return fs.readFile(req.file.path)
                .then(content => {
                    uploadImage("File.jpg", content);
                })
    })
```

With this code, everytime you upload a file to /register with the file content in the formdata, your image will be stored in /uploads folder on your backend and then to your S3 account. After the upload you can remove the file from the upload folder with

```
fs.remove(req.file.path)
```

Comment: Thanks @Pedro Silva will be giving it a shot tonight and will let you know how it goes

Comment: You may not need this line     AWS.config.update({ 'region': process.env.GROUP_REGION, 'accessKeyId': process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, 'secretAccessKey': process.env.AWS_SECRET_KEY })
 However, the rest should be ok, if everything goes ok mark me as a correct answer, if not, let me know what happnened

Comment: Will be updating you with the progress. Sorry had some delays

Comment: In my scenario, the file is located at the server though, so how do i use `multer` in a service basically. Is my question clear?

Comment: So, if the file is already on the server, you can ignore the multer library and just use the fs module to read the content of the file and call my function uploadImage to send the content to S3. Did you understand?

Comment: I will mark your answer as correct but for future reference. The result i am getting is kinda inconsistent it uploads the files but just fails at random times. Will investigate further

Comment: Hmm, I have used this code for 3 months and it was ok, maybe there is some problem with S3 but thanks :D